# Console Error in Angular- ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, typeerror, angular-console

Full Console error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data")

at Oviewer Component 15A11Selected (oviewer.component.ts:97:37)

at OviewerComponent.checkbeaLabel (aviewer.component.ts:114:22)

at Oviewer Component th 26 Template (oviewer.component.html:79:68)
```

Oviewer.component.html

```
<div class="stable mat-elevation-z8">

<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

<!-- Checkbox Column --> 
<ng-container matColumnDef="select">

<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>

<mat-checkbox

(change)="$event? toggleAllRows(): null" color="primary"

[checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"

[indeterminate]-"selection.hasValue() && lisAllSelected()"

[aria-label]="checkboxLabel()"

</mat-checkbox>
```

Oviewer.component.ts

```
iSAllSelected() {

const numSelected =this.selection.selected.length;

const numRows =this.dataSource.data.length;

return numSelected === numRows;

/** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection.*/

toggleAllRows() {

if (this.isAllSelected())

{

this.selection.clear();

return;

}

this.selection.select(...this.dataSource.data);

}

/** The label for the checkbox on the passed row */

checkboxLabel(row?: any): string { if (!row) { return ${this.isAllSelected() ? 'deselect' : 'select') all';

}
```

I am not able to found solution for this. Can someone help please why i am getting this Console error?

Answer (score 0):

You must look at the error message: it says that on the 97th line of `oviewer.component.ts` you try to access an objects 'data' property, but the object itself is not defined.

You did not provide the line numbers, but I suspect that that is this:

```
this.selection.select(...this.dataSource.data);
```

The datasource object is a wrapper around your data. So to use this, you must first initialize it (maybe in the class, or in the constructor with for instance `dataSource = new DataSource([])`) and then the Datasource will be ready for you to modify.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you made a validation before accessing "data". Example:

```
const numRows = this.dataSource && this.dataSource.data ? this.dataSource.data.length : [];
```

Comment: this is just hiding the original problem in the logic, and you add new functionality. If it is acceptable that the numRow can be assigned an empty array when the datasource is not defined, then it is fine. But this can have unwanted side effects.